# Use imploded result from MySql Query in PHP in_array() statement

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to use a string of coma separated values compiled from a mysql query within an `in_array()` statement. The problem is that the statement fails because the output of `$array` does not work in the `in_array()` function even though the pasted output of array does work...

```
$quiz = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM quiz WHERE quiz_page = '2'");
$array1=array();
while($quiz2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($quiz))
{
    $array1[]=$quiz2["id"];
}
$array = implode(",", $array1);
echo $array;
echo '<br>';

if (in_array(184, array($array))) {
echo '184 in $array';
} else {
echo '184 not in $array';
}
echo '<br>';

if (in_array(184, array(77,82,85,90,180,181,182,183,184,185))) {
echo '184 in array';
} else {
echo '184 not in array';
}
```

The result of the code above:

```
77,82,85,90,180,181,182,183,184,185
184 not in $array
184 in array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be checking `if (in_array(184, $array1)) {...` instead. `$array1` already contains each of numbers in a separate elements, like you have in your second `if` condition, e.g.

```
array(77,82,85,90,180,181,182,183,184,185)
```

When you do `array($array)` You get an array with *one element*, the entire imploded string, e.g

```
array("77,82,85,90,180,181,182,183,184,185")
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're doing with this, but it looks like you might be able to eliminate the whole `in_array` problem by just including the 184 in your query

```
SELECT id FROM quiz WHERE quiz_page = '2' AND id = 184
```

And checking whether or not the query returns anything.

Comment: This worked, thank you. The '184' was just for demonstration purposes. Is there a way to use the mysql querry in the in_array() function with a while loop?

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not really sure what you mean. From what I've seen, fetching in a while loop is the normal way to get your query results.